# Rotate анимация в android

Tags: android, анимация, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, необходимо реализовать следующее: использую анимацию вращения (`rotate y`) на картинке, 360 градусов. Когда угол поворота достигнет 270 градусов, необходимо сменить картинку, а потом допоказывать оставшиеся 90 градусов. Как такое реализовать? Есть идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, так сделать, конечно же, можно. Android предоставляет очень мощный по функционалу фреймворк для разработчиков, так что реализация абсолютно любой идеи - лишь вопрос времени.

**Решение:**

```
// ImageView для отображения изображений
final ImageView rot = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
rot.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage1));

// Анимация вращения View на 270 градусов
final RotateAnimation rotate270 = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,270.0f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
rotate270.setDuration(1500);
rotate270.setFillAfter(true);

// Анимация вращения View на 90 градусов
final RotateAnimation rotate90 = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,360.0f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
rotate90.setDuration(1500);
rotate90.setFillAfter(true);

// Запускаем множественную анимацию при клике по ImageView
rot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
            rot.startAnimation(rotate270);
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                  rot.setImageDrawable(getResources().
                                  getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                                  rot.startAnimation(rotate90);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },1500);
            }
        });
```

Это один из вариантов решения задачи. Так, например, можно анимацию вынести отдельно в ресурсы. Но я так никогда ни делаю, так как мне это кажется нецелесообразным - нет особых преимуществ перед выносом анимации в ресурсы приложения.

**P.S**  И, да, вы частенько задаете подобные вопросы, реализация которых достаточно просто и подробно описана в начальных главах учебников по фрейморку Android( например, Рето Майер пишет такие ). Не произойдет ничего страшного, если вы прочитаете одну из них - подобные вопросы у вас перестанут возникать вовсе.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: Советую ещё ознакомиться с этим http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator